# Vue JS - Putting Json on data

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I want to put my JSON data into Vue data, and a display, why can't I get to work?

```
compiled: function(){
    var self = this;
    console.log('teste');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'js/fake-ws.json',
        complete: function (data) {
            self.$data.musics = data;
            console.log(self.$data.musics);
        }
    })
}

<div id="playlist" class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul>
            <li v-repeat="musics.item" >
                <a href="">{{nome}}</a>
            </li>
        <ul>
    <div>
</div>
```

I can't get the code to work.. why?

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is that `musics` is not initially part of your Vue data, so when you set its value using `self.$data.musics = data`, Vue doesn't know it needs to watch it. Instead you need to use the `$add` method like this:
`self.$set("musics", data);`

From the VueJs Guide:

> In ECMAScript 5 there is no way to detect when a new property is added to an Object, or when a property is deleted from an Object. To deal with that, observed objects will be augmented with two methods: $add(key, value) and $delete(key). These methods can be used to add / delete properties from observed objects while triggering the desired View updates.

Answer (score 3):

`this` refers to the whole Vue object, so `musics` object is already accessible via `this.musics`. More info [here](http://vuejs.org/api/options.html) in the VueJS API reference and [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/#Model) in the VueJS guide, and more on `this` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

With that in mind the code should look something like this:

```
var playlist = new Vue({

 el: '#playlist',

 data:{
   musics: '',
 }

 methods: {
    compiled: function(){
      var self = this;
      console.log('test');

      $.ajax({
        url: 'js/fake-ws.json',
        complete: function (data) {
            self.musics = data
            console.log(self.musics);
        }
      })
    }
 }
```

And the view would be something like this:

```
<div id="playlist" class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                     <li v-repeat="musics">
                        <a href="">{{nome}}</a>
                    </li>
                <ul>
          </div>
    </div>
```

Also look at the code of [this example](http://vuejs.org/examples/commits.html).

Comment: I don't think compiled should be in the methods {}.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with vue-resource. Include vue-resource.js into your app or html file and:

```
    {
  // GET /someUrl
  this.$http.get('/someUrl').then(response => {

    // get body data
    this.someData = response.body;

  }, response => {
    // error callback
  });
}
```